Where did the soy and mustard taste go? A lentil shepherd's pie mystery
everyone. I love the website Budget Bytes and the Winter Lentil Stew there is a favorite (link here: https://www.budgetbytes.com/vegan-winter-lentil-stew/), thanks to the addition of mustard and soy. I wanted to incorporate that flavor into a lentil shepherd's pie, so I started with the Budget Bytes Vegetarian Shepherd's Pie (link here: https://www.budgetbytes.com/vegetarian-shepherds-pie/), and omitted the 1 tbsp of tomato paste in favor of 1.5 tbsp soy and 2 tbsp dijon mustard. I chose these amounts based on similar lentil shepherd's pie recipes. Oddly enough, while I could smell the mustard and soy while cooking, the flavor was all but gone when I ate it. I can't figure out where it went! The lentil stew has the same amounts of both seasoning and lentils and the flavor comes through beautifully. Did the flour in the shepherd's pie neutralize it somehow? Thanks!

is it underwhelming in the dish as a whole, or can you not taste it in the "filling" when eaten alone?

I'm not sure I understand. The "filling" IS the entire dish, aside from the mashed potato on top, and I wouldn't expect to taste it there. But the flavor was underwhelming in every bite.

Mustard loses it‘s characteristic flavor if heated, especially if heated over a longer time. If you want that bite, you need to find a way to add it late in the process.

Exactly, I'm assuming by bite you mean both filling and mash at the same time. I'm asking if it tastes fine without the mash. That would imply a dilution problem.

Please avoid writing just "soy" when you mean soy sauce / shoyu! This can be quite confusing, though here it is fairly clear from the context.

Lightbender, there is no mustard in the mash.
